# A free Commercial-Use Application server for Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish, websphere, application-server

Is there a free Commercial-Use Application-Server ?

I found a chart on Wikipedia("Comparison of application servers"), which says that JSAS (now GlassFish) and IBM WebSphere are free.

I am not sure about this, but it seems that:

- GlassFish is [no longer free](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf).
- WebSphere is [not totally free, because of socket pricing(?)](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS210-310).

Am I correct? 
Is Apache Geronimo is free for commercial use?

Comment: WebSphere Community Edition is free as far as i understand.If you need support yes you got to pay for it (and that is where pricing options like socket pricing is available)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jboss and Glassfish are great examples of application servers free for commercial use, you have to distinguish the difference between free use and support, both of them are free to use but if you want to get same support (not talking here about forums etc) you would have to probably pay for it.

Answer (score 7):

**Glassfish Community Edition is free** and powerful (Full Java EE 6 platform support).

**GlassFish Server Open Source Edition**

- Free community-supported application server
- Full Java EE 6 platform support
- The best open source application server in the industry today
- Next-generation modular and extensible architecture (OSGi)
- Enterprise reliability and performance with full clustering

---

**JBoss Community Server is also free** but JBoss Enterprise is not.

It is free for commercial use. You can develop your applications and deploy them in production environment on top of JBoss without having to pay anything.

**Here is the feature differences of two edition:**

[image]

---

**Both of this solutions offer enterprise level support with a fee.**

Answer (score 2):

If it is free, then why Jboss clearly states that "[downloads are for development use only](https://www.jboss.org/products/eap.html)"?!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere Liberty Profile starting from 8.5.5.6 is fully Java EE 7 application server. It is free for development and for production usage with certain restrictions (2GB RAM per using organization). For more details check [websphere-application-server-everyone](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-application-server-everyone/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10487775)

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan From my point of view, key information is there - free and restriction of 2GB - but feel free to edit this post and add any other information form the link you consider 'essential'

Answer (score 0):

JBoss is free too (we are using it).